# Unzip folder gives FileNotFound Exception in android

Tags: android, unzip

I am trying unzip zip folder to folder, it works and it  unzipped some folder but When it takes index.html it gives error like this,I want to unzip files to folder but  I got a error,How can I solve this problem?

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.kocsistem.pixageoneandroid/files/Contents/widgetContent/ab34f7fe018a45f0a43d3139d6986b84/index.html (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:308)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:238)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:180)
        at com.kocsistem.pixageoneandroid.utils.Utils.unpackZip(Utils.java:454)
        at
```

My unzip funtion,it works but for index.html it gives above error

```
public static void unpackZip(String src, String dest, String folderName){

    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(src);
        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream));
        ZipEntry zipEntry;

        while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null){

            String zipEntryName = zipEntry.getName();

            String name = dest.substring(dest.lastIndexOf("/")-1);

            File FileName = new File(dest);
            if (!FileName.isDirectory()) {
                try {
                    if (FileName.mkdir()) {
                    } else {
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            File file = new File(dest+ "/" + folderName +"/" +zipEntryName);

            if (file.exists()){

            } else {
                if(zipEntry.isDirectory()){
                    file.mkdirs();
                }else{
                    byte buffer[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream, BUFFER_SIZE);
                    int count;

                    while ((count = zipInputStream.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                        bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }

                    bufferedOutputStream.flush();
                    bufferedOutputStream.close();
                }
            }
        }
        zipInputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build.gradle

zip4j `implementation 'com.github.joielechong:zip4jandroid:1.0.1'`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}
```

Code

```
String source = destFilePath + "/" + fileNameList.get(i);
String target = destFilePath.getAbsolutePath();

    try {
           ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
           zipFile.extractAll(target);
         } catch (ZipException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           }
```

Comment: thanks,it works and don't give FileNotFound Exception

Answer (score 0):

Try use below code:

1.First zip files are create

```
                File FPath = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + folderName);
                if (FPath.exists()) FPath.delete();
                String mPath = folder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + folderName+ ".zip";



                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPath);
                InputStream is = cn.getInputStream();
                int bytesRead = 0;
                byte[] buf = new byte[8096];
                long total = 0;
                int progress;
                int count = i;
                while ((bytesRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    total += bytesRead;
                    fos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                if (is != null) is.close();
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                }
```

2.When files are created

```
 unpackZip(folder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator, folderName);
```

3.Your function

```
 private boolean unpackZip(String path, String folderName) {

    InputStream is;
    ZipInputStream zis;
    try {
        String filename;
        is = new FileInputStream(path + folderName+ ".zip");
        zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
        ZipEntry ze;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count;

        File refolder = new File(path + folderName);
        if (!refolder.exists())
            refolder.mkdirs();


        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            filename = ze.getName();
            if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                File fmd = new File(refolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename);
                fmd.mkdirs();
                continue;
            }

            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(refolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename);
            while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }

            fout.close();
            zis.closeEntry();
        }

        zis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        File mFF = new File(path + folderName+ ".zip");
        mFF.delete();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `if (!refolder.exists())
            if (!refolder.mkdirs()) { Toast( ... sorry could not create directory... ); return;}`

Comment: `File fmd = new File(refolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename);` Better: `File fmd = new File(refolder, filename);`

Comment: `is = new FileInputStream(path + folderName+ ".zip");` Wrong. That should be `is = new FileInputStream(path);` as you can see at original post.

Comment: ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
            folder = cw.getDir("Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: @blackapps sorry please check now

Comment: `copyAssets(refolder.getAbsolutePath());` That statement makes no sense at all as it is not somethong OP wants. You better had removed that statement. And reacted to my other remarks which you did not.

Comment: copyAssets(refolder.getAbsolutePath()); This was for my process. does not metter.